# C# Passing a byte array as a Get Parameter to a web service using HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to call a webservice from a third party company to authorize my access. The flow works in this way. The third party app calls my api controller action passing a string parameter (token) which represents a Guid(client id). After that, I need to call their other service to check if that received "token" is still valid(authorized). The problem is that the second call requires me to send the guid as a byte array. I tried a lot but couldn't figure out how to send the Guid converted in a byte array as a Get parameter. Here is my code. This returns a Bad Request.

```
private async Task<User> VerifyTokenAsync(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytesToken = new Guid(token).ToByteArray();

            string serviceUrl = string.Format("http://third.party.RequestTokenAuthorization?token={0}", bytesToken);

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(serviceUrl)))
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();                        
                }
                else
                {                        
                    //todo
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.SaveError(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The URL after adding the byte array looks like this:
http://third.party/RequestTokenAuthorization?token=System.Byte[]

Obs: I added the service as a ServiceReference in my project, and calling it using the client generated method works:

```
byte[] bytes = new Guid(token).ToByteArray();

ServiceReference1.Client client = new ServiceReference1.Client();

var response = client.RequestTokenAuthorization(bytes);
```

I'm not sure but since I'm working with a asp.net web api, it seems "wrong" to me adding service reference to my project.

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like OAuth, but if so, why not say? What you are asking is very api-specific, so please clarify with exactly what technology you are using. Also, if it works, what is the issue?

Comment: It works only when I add the external service as a Service Reference in my Asp.Net Web API project. But I would prefer not to, unless there is no other way.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could cut and paste the generated code?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not getting your point. All my code is there, the second portion, is exactly what I did adding the service as a service reference.

Comment: What does the URL look like after you've attached the Byte array to it?

Comment: I've added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

OK, your problem is very easy to see:

`token=System.Byte[]`

That is what happens when you call ToString() on a byte array, which is what String.Format does.  Since I don't know what your input string shows, I would try the following options one at a time in this order:

1. Leave the string as-is, and pass directly to your request URL.
2. Convert to a guid, and call `new Guid(token).ToString("N")`;
3. Use `Convert.ToBase64(bytesToken)` to create a Base-64 string for your URL.

Try and please post back with results.

Comment: The first and second option I had tried already, no success. Tested now the third option, also no success, all of them give me a Bad Request status. Anyway I ended up adding a service reference because of project urgency. Thanks for you help anyway.